# fprintf in MacOS,not opening file

Tags: c, macos

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    fp=fopen("tyxaioi.txt","w");
    if(fp==NULL)
        printf("Den vre8ike\n");
    for(i=1;i<=25;i++)
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n",i);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;  
}
```

I have to open a file and write some numbers and a string in it. To see how `fopen`, `fprintf`, `fscanf` etc. work, I wrote this little program. I have Mac OS and I write in Xcode. I ran this program and nothing happens. I think it doesn't create the file. Can anyone help me understand if I have a mistake in my program?

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: I don't have and OSx terminal up, but it worked for me on debian, with gcc 4.7. Do you have write permissions in the current directory?

Comment: Where are you looking for the file?  Xcode runs programs in a weird subdirectory someplace, which might not be where you'd expect.

Comment: Doesn't it even print `"Den vre8ike"` (What ever it means ;-)?

Comment: my first answer was wrong. You may check now, it's correct.

Comment: Guys thanks..it seems that the problem was that in mac u must put the full path directory to open a file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file **is created** but you don't know where it is.

As the filename is not preceeded by a directory path you're creating the file in the **current working directory**, that is (for a program run in Xcode) the directory where the executable is created at build time.

To find your **text file** named `tyxaioi.txt` first activate your Xcode project's window.

On the left sidebar open the folder **Products**, you should see an icon that represents the executable.

Right-click that icon and select "Show in Finder"

In the same directory you will see your text file.

If that behaviour is not what you want you may specify an absolute path, for example

```
fp=fopen("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/tyxaioi.txt","w");
```

substitute `xxxx` with the name of your home folder; the file will be created on the Desktop.

---

Btw: if you're unable to open the file you should print a message with a meaning and exit (or handle the error):

```
if(fp==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open the file for writing.\n");
    return 1; // <====
}
```

Comment: OP's code creates a file in the *current working directory*, not at `/`.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because of the line that reads: Right-click that icon and select "Show in Finder".  My output file was hidden away in the directory Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[Project name]-[long lowercase string]/Build/Products/Debug/, unrevealed by searching in the Finder, and finally revealed by this answer's suggestion.